# remove all strings from microtime and add minutes to it

Tags: php, microtime

im usng this code to get php microtime

```
$date = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

the echo result i get like this

```
1.42020381242E+12
```

how do i make sure the microtime is just numbers no special characters or strings like this

```
1420209804538
```

on the localhost everything was ok and getting just numbers BUT on the server it's gettings numbers and String and a dot(.)

**Question 2**

also how do i added more 15 minute to the current microtime

Comment: The value is a real number; it's echo that is rendering it in scientific format, based on the [precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) setting.... display using sprint() or similar to ensure that it is not displayed in scientific format

Comment: And to add 15 minutes, just add 15 * 60 * 1000

Comment: @MarkBaker where do i add that ? could you post it as answer :)

Comment: `$date += 15 * 60 * 1000;`

Comment: @MarkBaker i get that and it worked perfect, could you please provide example for the integer numbers only and please post it all as answer to mark it and accepted answer

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, it's * 1000 Not / 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) to sanitize the variable to only hold numerical values, using [`FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

For example;

```
echo filter_var($date, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Using Mark Bakers comment, to add 15 minutes, you would just do the following;

```
echo filter_var( ($date + 15 * 60 * 1000), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

https://eval.in/238951

### Edit

You can use a regular expression to remove any characters that are not numeric. For example

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $date);
```

### Edit 2

You can capture the last part of the string by using the following regular expression

```
$re = "~\s(\d+)~"; 
$str = "12 + 142020602353 "; 
preg_match($re, $str, $m);
echo $m[0];
```

https://eval.in/238955

Comment: Very good but still have the +12 in the time take a look [h e r e](http://www.twaa9l.com/date.php)

Comment: should i use ``str_replace`` or there is someway to remove that ?

Comment: this is a good way using ``preg_replace`` BUT it will keep the 12 number at the end which it will make time wrong

Comment: You realise that the value you're trying to remove the string data from isn't actually a string but a float?

Comment: @MarkBaker it was string i fixed it by using very simple code ``(int)(microtime(true)*1000);``

Comment: Then perhaps you should advise that PHP documents team that the docs for [round()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) are incorrect, because that's pretty clear that you should get a __float__ returned, not a __string__: `float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )`

Comment: Or if your problem is with [microtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) then that also should return a float if the `$get_as_float` argument is true.